# How can i make an image slider in HTML?

Tags: html

[This "image slider? thing. What is it called?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al0br.png)

If you go to myanimelist.net, there is this very nice and simple image slider and upon clicking it, it redirects you to the specific anime details page according to what you clicked. What is this widget called and where can I learn to create something like this?

A beginner programmer that wants to create a website but no idea how to start.

Comment: Typically it's called a carousel or image slider. If you search for these you'll likely be able to find existing ones you can use.

Answer (score 1):

The page uses css mostly. if you are really starting and want to learn try with JQuery is a Java framework with "widgets" like you call them.

a duplicate of what you need is here: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Fully-Responsive-Flexible-jQuery-Carousel-Plugin-slick/

Answer (score 1):

This is image slider or carousel slider. You can make it easy by using bootstrap 4 carousels. Bootstrap is very easy to learn and for image slider, you don't need to learn Jquery. Here is a link which will help you to make carousal [Bootstrap Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)

If you wanna use direct code then you can check this link [Jassor Image slider](https://www.jssor.com/demos/image-slider.slider)

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [Carousel or Slider](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13951/what-is-the-difference-between-a-slider-a-gallery-and-a-carousel). You should be able to create this with just `HTML` and `CSS` and a tad bit of `JavaScript`. I first learnt building one by going through [this link in W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp). When I got older and experienced I stopped building one from scratch for every project, instead started using [Bootstrap Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/carousel/). A good resource to learn this is from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp).